# client.on is not a function (not discord.js related)

Tags: node.js

I'm creating my own package that needs to do some emitting from the package to the main file.

This simplified module gets what I'm trying to achieve:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

module.exports.client = async function(username,password,version) {

    // Do login code here
    this.emit("login", loginData)
}
```

Then my test code runs that with

```
var client = new require("../index").client("username","password","0.774")

client.on("login",function(data) {
    console.log(data)
})
```

With every time, the program returning

```
client.on("login",function(data) {
       ^

TypeError: client.on is not a function
```

Has anyone had a similar issue? This is my first time making a module in this style, so please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your function `client()` exported from `index.js` is declared with the `async` keyword, it will return a `Promise` rather than an actual value passed to the return statement. Assuming the value you return from the function `client()` is an object with an `on()` function, then in order to access this function you either need to `await` the result of `client()` or you need to use the `.then()` function on promise. Example:

```
var clientPromise = new require("../index").client("username","password","0.774")

clientPromise.then(client => {
  client.on("login",function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
});
```

While you could also use `await` on the result of the `client()` function, this is not allowed in all contexts, and so you would have to wrap the code that does this in another async function.

Comment: I figured how to get around this with a different approach similar to yours, but thank you lots!